Ranges in CMap files
In a CMap file (for use in PostScript or PDF documents), is it allowed to have CID ranges where the start end end codes differ in more than the last byte?  For example, would the following be valid?
1 begincodespacerange
<3030> <3232>
endcodespacerange

1 begincidrange
<3030> <3232> 34
endcidrange

If this is valid, which code would be used for CID 35?  Is guess it should be code <3031>, but I didn't find any documentation which actually makes this explicit.
If checked the following references, but did not find the answers there:

https://adobe-type-tools.github.io/font-tech-notes/pdfs/5099.CMapResources.pdf
https://adobe-type-tools.github.io/font-tech-notes/pdfs/5014.CIDFont_Spec.pdf
https://www.adobe.com/jp/print/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf#page=396
https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf#page=280

Did I miss any documentation which has more detail?

I am asking about CID mappings (using cidrange), not ToUnicode mappings (using bfchar).  Also, my understanding is that CIDs are assigned "sequentially" (see e.g. bottom of 386 in the PLRM), and while I'm not sure what this means in my example, I don't think this would allow for numbers to be "in any order".

@KJ The only cidrange I see on this web page is <0000304b> <0000304c> 2, where only the last byte varies.  Am I missing something?

To answer your three questions:

Yes, but it is not recommended. Some CMap resource consumers may
complain.
Yes, but it is not recommended. Some CMap resource
consumers may complain.
3031.
See the first post by K J. (now removed) linked to https://ccjktype.fonts.adobe.com/2012/03/building-utf32-cmaps.html

Note that your codespacerange definition is for a total of nine code points: 3030, 3031, 3032, 3130, 3131, 3132, 3230, 3231, and 3232.

Thanks Ken.  I re-read the link you list under 4, but I see very little information about CID ranges there.  The only cidrange I find there is <0000304b> <0000304c>, where only the last byte varies. Am I missing something?
